# Cygwin or Gnuwin32 or MYSYS?

Tags: c, windows, fork, openmpi

I've tried to google it and I understood some stuff, but still don't know which one is suitable for my needs.
all I want to do is to compile C file (or C++) under Unix environment (so I can use Fork and stuff that don't work on windows) and run these files after compiling it.

to be more exact, I need to use Fork+Semaphores and to use OpenMPI. I know I can do these with Cygwin (or that's what I understood), but it seems like it has a very large size, so I thought if this Gnuwin32 or MYSYS can do what I want to do and they have less size then Cygwin, then it's better ?

Comment: cygwin is better, maintained by red hat, and contains more packages. mingw is very old. cygwin provides a POSIX compatible runtime environment, while mingw does not.

Comment: @self MSYS1 is very old, [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/) is very new (and has a huge repository of packages). MinGW.org is quite stale, [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) is very much up to speed. Please stop spreading false truths.

Comment: @rubenvb and can I use this MinGW-w64 to compile and run my files as they're in linux ?

Comment: @Mohe no, MinGW-w64 GCC is a native Win32 GCC, which links to the Windows runtime and OS libraries. Apart from pthreads, MinGW-w64 doesn't provide much of POSIX, because Cygwin already does that. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure you *require* fork and cannot instead use a more platform independent way of multiprocessing (a thin `fork`/`CreateProcess` wrapper) or multithreading (`pthreads`, `Boost.Thread`, C++11 `std::thread`, ...), then you are forcing yourself to use Cygwin.

Note that Cygwin's `fork` is pretty much as efficient as `fork` can get on Windows, which is not very, as the OS wasn't designed with that operation in mind, hence the kernel level support is missing.

Cygwin itself is not that big: it's only a DLL you link to that provides the POSIX interface. But do note that Cygwin is GPL and linking to the Cygwin DLL will force copyleft on your project as well.

Comment: yeah, I need to use "fork" no other. and I didn't get the last part, but I guess I'm going with Cygwin.

Comment: Yes, don't use cygwin if you want to develop closed source, proprietary software.

Comment: @Mohe the last part says two things: 1) to redistribute your apps built with cygwin, you'll only need the DLL, not the whole software distribution. 2) If you use Cygwin, you can't write closed source or BSD/MIT/Apache/... licensed software. It'll have to be GPL or comparable as well.